# Is it possible to issue a valid user session based on a valid access-token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We have an app redirects the users for some functions into web views.
The app starts an oidc flow to retrieve access and refresh tokens.
The app also retrieves a session cookie and a long term cookie for the web views that the user potentially uses.
For retrieving user information in the web views the user device needs the session cookie. If the session cookie is expired the long term cookie is used the renew the session cookie.

This seems like the refresh token and the long term cookie have overlapping functionality.

Is it possible to issue a user session cookie based on a valid access token?

I want to know if:

1. is it technically possible?
2. is it secure?